# Long file name stops pull from github.com

Tags: git, github

When creating a file through the github.com web interface, an accident occurred where the contents of the file were pasted into the new file name text box.  This created a really long file name in the github repository.  The filename contained double quotes, single quotes, utf-8 weird quotes from M$ Word etc...

After this file was created, a pull request would not work.  I got an error stating that git could not create this file.

As I can't pull this file on windows or linux, I can't remove/commit and push back to the repository.  Is there a way of remotely deleting files in a git repository in github.com?

Additional:

I can't edit the file in github, as clicking on the really long file name causes github to spin.

Comment: Is this file the only thing that changed in the commit? / Is undoing the commit an option?

Comment: I don't know if you can undo something if you can't clone the working repository?  Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote to GitHub support about this, they said:

> "Will,
>
> Okay, yes. That is a long name. We should not let that happen. Thanks
>   very much for pointing this out.
>
> We don't currently have a way to delete a file from the web, but I
>   think it's pretty obvious we've been thinking about it and going in
>   that direction. I'm going to tell the people working in that area
>   about this incident."

In case it helps anyone else out, for windows, I came up with a solution that uses the DOS 8.3 naming convention.  I created a file in DOS that the uses the first six characters of the long file name plus a tilde, and then the numeric index.

In this case, I created a file in my working directory called `02_RUL~2`.  Then I could do git status, which showed the name change, then I could commit that, push to the repository, and then delete the new short file name, without ever having to pull the existing file down from the repository.  Who would have thought that stupid naming convention would help some day?

Answer (score 2):

Run these commands (assuming you are talking about the master branch):

```
git clone --no-checkout *my-repo*
cd *repo*
git branch -f master origin/master^
git push -f origin master
```

This clones the repo without checking out and then sets the master branch by one
commit.

Answer (score 0):

In github web interface you can click `Edit` on this file. In Edit mode you can rename file.